# Fireworks CS4 - Editing the size of the background of an animated .gif without changing the size of the sprite

Tags: animation, adobe-fireworks, cs4

I have an animated .gif which I'd like to modify.  Specifically, I'd like to be able to make the background/canvas slightly larger without it affecting the actual animated sprite.  Is there a reasonable way to do this in Adobe Fireworks CS4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after a bit of trial and error.  Fireworks allows one to change the size of the underlying canvas without affecting the layers on top.  Worked perfectly once I found the option.

Comment: How were you able to find that?